# Erro após 100 solicitações AJAX

Tags: mysql, ajax, banco-de-dados

Tenho a função abaixo que faz um solicitação a cada segundo ao banco MySQL e atualiza uma DIV na página. Mas depois de mais ou menos 100 solicitações o "ACHO EU" banco de dados bloqueia e retorna "Ocorreu um erro na solicitação ajax". O que poderia ser?

função ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function UpdateValues() {
            $(function() {

                $.ajax({
                    data: {
                     'option': "telaValues"
                    },

                    url: './GetValores',
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(data) {

                        queryObject = eval('(' + JSON.stringify(data) + ')');
                        queryObjectLen = queryObject.jsonArray.length;

                        var varTensao = queryObject.jsonArray[0].jsonTensao;
                        var varCorrente = queryObject.jsonArray[0].jsonCorrente;
                        //alert(per);
                        document.getElementById("tensaoH1").innerHTML = "Tensão: "+varTensao+" V";
                        document.getElementById("correnteH2").innerHTML ="Corrente: "+varCorrente+" A";

                    },

                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        alert("Error! " + xhr.error);
                        alert("Ocorreu um erro na requisição ajax");
                    }
                });

            });
        }
    </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

                $(document).ready(function(){
                    setInterval(UpdateValues, 1000);
                    });
        </script>
```

SERVLET:

```
.
.
else if(op.equals("telaValues")){
                 try {

         JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
         JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject();
         ResultSet rs = null;


            rs = null;
            request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");  
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");  
            response.setContentType("application/json");   
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

                    //JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject();
rs = new GrandezasDAO().rs("SELECT tensao,corrente from consumo1 order by id desc limit 1");// where mes_ref BETWEEN '"+firstDate+"' AND  '"+secondDate+"");
                    //JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();  

                     //JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject();

                     while(rs.next()){ 
                         JSONObject js = new JSONObject(); 
                          js.put("jsonTensao", rs.getInt("tensao")); 
                          //js.put("temp", rs.getInt("temperatura"));
                          js.put("jsonCorrente", rs.getDouble("corrente"));  
                          jsonArray.put(js);  
                     }  

                     responseObj.put("jsonArray", jsonArray);
                     out.print(responseObj);  
                     //out.flush();



        } catch (JSONException e) {  
                     e.printStackTrace();  
        }

      }
.
.
```

RETORNO DO Alert de error:(após 100 buscas no MySQL)

```
Error! function() {
    if (u) {
        var t = u.length;
        (function i(t) {
            b.each(t, function(t, n) {
                var r = b.type(n);
                "function" === r ? e.unique && p.has(n) || u.push(n) : n && n.length && "string" !== r && i(n)
            })
        })(arguments), n ? o = u.length : r && (s = t, c(r))
    }
    return this
}
```

RETORNO DO Alert de status:

```
200
```

Comment: E o que aparece neste alerta `alert("Error! " + xhr.error);` ?

Comment: Acrescentei o retorno do Erro, mas não é dá para entender muito a que se refere...

Comment: E no NetBeans ele retorna o erro: Grave:   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema, era um método do Servlet que retornava um ResultSet e não fechava a conexão com o MySQL.